# Option "mustexist=False" in askdirectory (tkinter)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to display a folder selection dialog with tkinter in Python, using `tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory`.

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/dialog.html#tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory) say there is an option called:

> mustexist - determines if selection must be an existing directory.

I'd suppose it means by setting `mustexist = False`, I can enter any arbitrary non-existent path into the bar at the top or the bottom and when hitting "Select folder", it should just return this path without asserting that it exists. Doing so however, an error saying "path does not exist" still appears, preventing dialog return.

Code to reproduce:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
print(askdirectory(mustexist=False))
```

*(tested on Python3.6 + 3.7 on Windows)*

Do I missunderstand something here? Or does it indeed just not work as it should?

Comment: have u tried leaving it empty? like `print(askdirectory())`

Comment: Yes, I tried leaving it empty and also setting `mustexist` to `0` or `tk.FALSE` or even `True`... it's all the same behavior. @CoolCloud

Comment: must be a bug or somethin :(

Comment: Maybe this is a platform-specific problem. When I run your code on OSX I'm able to create a new folder.

Comment: Good to know @BryanOakley, so at least my code is not the problem :/

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering too and this is the *exact* behaviour in OSX:

If you **don't** set it at all, you get an option to create a new folder in form of a "new folder" button in the dialog.

If you set it to **True**, you don't get that button, but CMD-N still allows you to create a folder.

If you set it to **False**, you cannot create a folder anymore.